# How to Corrupt your database to check your sql integirty check logic is working?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-scripts

I have written scripts for database maintains plan

now i want to test my script

i dont have any currpted database then how can i belive my integirty check script giving right error message if my DB is corrpted

i want to corrpt my database to test this how to corrpt the databse :)

DBCC CHECKDB WITH NO_INFOMSGS;
GO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paul Randal has some corrupted databases on the the SQL Skills site.

See www.sqlskills.com

http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/corruption-demo-databases-and-scripts/

Comment: thanks but i am still searching how to corrupt db so that i can check with my own database

Answer (score 1):

For a possible test scenario, drop constraints and/or triggers, corrupt your data (i.e. set former-foreign key references to NULL) then see if your script detects the corruption.

Comment: It is not possible to corrupt the database that way. SQL Server *never* allows it. Or maybe I misunderstood your definition of corrupt?

Comment: its looks easy but difficult to implement this theory in practical still working on this didn't found any success

Comment: You can't drop constraints or triggers on SQL server?

Comment: I consider broken relations to be corruption of my data integrity. I hope you do, too. But that's not the same as corruption of the memory or storage layer, which also threatens data integrity, but you didn't indicate that much.

Answer (score 0):

Get to the internal services and delete stuff that looks important. If that is not what you want then copy all the files onto a flash drive and repeatedly eject it incorrectly - eventually it will be corrupted. Then upload it back onto the server machine and check. But the likelihood is that your script will be corrupted